Old show with four kids who were like detectives for their school and would fight monsters whenever they solved a case
It was a show I used to love and watch all the time, maybe from like 2016.
It had like four kids who were like detectives for their school, but they could like turn into cartoons and they had like a cartoon car they drove around and there were like monsters they had to defeat. They were always solving cases in the school and whenever they solved one there was always like a monster they had to fight, but they were like detectives.
The show was on Netflix, I know that for sure. I just really need to find it, so please, anybody out there who knows this show, please tell me.

Was the show fully animated or a combination of live-action and animation?

Also, how did the kids fight the monsters? Did they have powers or weapons/tools?

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Is this Team Toon (2015)...?
From TV Tropes:

Four kids named Dylan, Sam, Ash, and Iko form a club called Team Toon, drawn together by their shared love of cartooning. In their club they produce the popular online viral series called "Psycho Squirrel", and they are popular at their school for their creation. However, their club isn't just a hobby. Dylan discovers that they have the power to make their cartoon creations come to life and use it to form a superhero squad of the same name to fight rogue cartoon monsters that take over the minds of innocent humans. They have their own cartoon masks, a Cool Car with a wise-cracking AI, and even Psycho Squirrel himself as a secret weapon. Episodes revolve around mysteries going in and around the school caused by monsters.
Team Toon is an American hybrid live-action/animated television show for European Cartoon Network. [...]
Made its United States premiere on Netflix on June 15th, 2015.
[...]
Monster of the Week: Subverted: at least more than one monster appears each episode.

The show features a mix of live-action and 2D animation and premiered on Netflix a year before you said you watched it. The protagonists are four kids who can turn into cartoon characters, drive around in a cartoon car, solve mysteries around their school and fight monsters.




I like your answer better than mine. :-D

Might it be Code Lyoko: Evolution?

The series centers on a group of teenagers who travel to the virtual world of Lyoko to battle against a malignant artificial intelligence known as XANA who once again threatens Earth with its extraordinary abilities to access the real world and cause trouble via activating one of ten towers on each of Lyoko's five regions, excluding its Forest and Ice regions.
The scenes in the real world employ live-action with hand-painted backgrounds, while the scenes on Lyoko and the Cortex are presented in 3D CGI animation. It premiered on January 5, 2013 on France 4 and 30 November 2013 on Canal J. It blends live-action with 3D CGI animation, picking up where the original series left off. In addition to improving upon the CGI in the original series, the soundtrack has been overhauled as well.

Trailer



